# How to make sticky bar in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm novice in **SwiftUI** and still can't understand how to make sticky bar on the top of the `List`. Like letters in apple music app when you listing artists or songs (look [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI5NS.gif)).

I explored abilities of the `List` and `NavigationView`, but got nothing.

Comment: Apple's official SwiftUI tutorials covers this..

Comment: Nope, SwiftUI tutorials do not contain anything about Section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SwiftUI’s` list view has built-in support for sections and section headers, just like `UITableView` in `UIKit`. To add a section around some cells, start by placing a `Section` around it.

What we want to do is create a list view that has two sections: one for important tasks and one for less important tasks. Here’s how that looks:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Important tasks")) {
                TaskRow()
                TaskRow()
                TaskRow()
            }

            Section(header: Text("Other tasks")) {
                TaskRow()
                TaskRow()
                TaskRow()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Credit: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-sections-to-a-list

Comment: I thought this question was about sticky headers?  I wonder why this answer is marked correct.  These are not sticky headers.

Comment: They are sticky if you set the listStyle to .plain

Answer (score 10):

`LazyVStack` provides an initializer with a `pinnedView` parameter that does exactly this.

Comment: For very long lists, lazyVstack is too slow.  We need a solution for List

Answer (score 9):

Use `pinnedViews` in the `LazyVStack` initializer.

```
LazyVStack(pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
    Section(header: Text("Sticky Header")) {
        ForEach(0...3) { item in
            Text(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use List style `.listStyle(PlainListStyle())` on List and use `Section` on iOS 13 +

for Example

```
 struct ContentView: View {
  var content = MyData()
    var body: some View {
      List {
        ForEach(content.sections, id: \.title) { section in
          Section(content: {
            ForEach(section.rows, id: \.self) { row in
              Text(row)
            }
          }, header: {
            Text(section.title)
          })
        }
      }
      .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    }
}
```

Given:

```
struct MyData {
  struct Section {
    var title: String
    var rows: [String]
  }

  var sections: [Section] = []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SwiftUI How to make sticky Header View or header stay on the top of each Section/cell in List.**

**Steps:**

1. 1- Add Scroll View

   2- Use forEach in scroll view

   3- Use LazyVStack inside forEach and add pinnedView as section header in LazyVStack

   4- Inside LazyVStack use Section with header

Sample Code:

```
@State var headerTitleArray = ["28 Jun, 15:00","29 July, 15:00","30 Aug, 15:00","31 Sep, 15:00","1 Oct, 15:00"]
```

For Example we have this array of header titles in it.

```
ScrollView {
    ForEach(0..<headerTitleArray.count, id: \.self) { listIndex in
    
        LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {

            Section {
                ForEach(0..<10, id: \.self) { landmark in
                //MARK: - Items in per section
                    Text("section items")
                }
            
            } header: {

                //MARK: - Seaction header title

                Text("\(headerTitleArray(listIndex))")
                .font(AppFont(size: 18,type: "Medium"))
                .foregroundColor(AppColors.labelColor)
                .padding(.vertical,12)
                .padding(.horizontal,16)
        }
    }
}//foreach } //scrollView
```

[image: This image indicates in steps that when you scroll the header stays on the top of list until next header comes to current header place]

Answer (score 0):

> This is easier way to use Sticky Header try this approach and let me
> know is it working...

```
    struct LatestMagazineView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    let columns = [GridItem(.flexible()),GridItem(.flexible())]
    @State  var searchText: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            VStack(spacing:0) {
                Color.orange.ignoresSafeArea().frame(height: 25)
                ScrollView{
                    VStack(spacing: 0){
                        
                        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "")){img in
                            img.resizable().frame(height: 225)
                            
                        }placeholder: {
                            Image("Anoop").resizable().frame(height: 225)
                        }
                        Image("soft").resizable().frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 65, alignment: .leading)
                        
                        
                        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 10, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]){
                            Section(header:
                                        VStack{
                                TextField("Enter Search Text...", text: $searchText).font(.title)
                                
                                    .padding(4)
                                    .padding(.leading,searchText.isEmpty ? 29 : 4)
                                
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                
                                    .cornerRadius(8)
                                    .overlay(
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 22)
                                            .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                                    )}.padding(6).background(Color.yellow)
                            ) {
                                ForEach(0..<21){_ in
                                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                                        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "")){ img in
                                            img .resizable()
                                                .frame(height: 255)
                                        }placeholder: {
                                            Image("soft")
                                                .resizable()
                                                .frame(height: 255)
                                        }
                                    }.padding(8).background(Color.white).cornerRadius(4).shadow(radius: 1)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```